# openstack nova resize fail : nova.exception.NoValidHost: No valid host was found

Tags: openstack, ubuntu-20.04, openstack-nova

I have got a VM in VMware on which openstack is installed. Openstack has two instances (2GB,1VCPU and 4GB,4VCPU). I changed the size of one of the instance  having 4GB, 4VCPU to 8 GB using nova resize and it worked. Now I need RAM atleast 16 GB and VCPUs 6 but the resize command finishes way too early (within seconds) without generating error and RAM size has not upgraded.

I finally found following error in nova-conductor.log

```
nova.exception.NoValidHost: No valid host was found. 
: nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found. 
2022-05-09 10:57:11.622 56 WARNING nova.scheduler.utils [req-31c98f42-d465-4773-9b4a-3474aef85a1c 10f23c55b2ce420aa1e757062f3874f8 c458f62c51d249ef9bf2b9f11c4ddb98 - default default] [instance: 7b0e27e4-8c78-4dc5-bf38-3cfc02d356d8] Setting instance to ACTIVE state.: nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found. 
2022-05-09 11:01:46.757 55 WARNING nova.scheduler.utils [req-cfa535cc-c19f-4b75-8fde-224d8f3610d5 10f23c55b2ce420aa1e757062f3874f8 c458f62c51d249ef9bf2b9f11c4ddb98 - default default] Failed to compute_task_migrate_server: No valid host was found. 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/server.py", line 241, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nova/scheduler/manager.py", line 209, in select_destinations
raise exception.NoValidHost(reason="")

nova.exception.NoValidHost: No valid host was found. 
: nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found. 
2022-05-09 11:01:46.759 55 WARNING nova.scheduler.utils [req-cfa535cc-c19f-4b75-8fde-224d8f3610d5 10f23c55b2ce420aa1e757062f3874f8 c458f62c51d249ef9bf2b9f11c4ddb98 - default default] [instance: 7b0e27e4-8c78-4dc5-bf38-3cfc02d356d8] Setting instance to ACTIVE state.: nova.exception_Remote.NoValidHost_Remote: No valid host was found.
```

I have read in some articles that changing `ram_allocation_ratio` and `cpu_allocation_ratio` will work but I dont know exactly how I should change it in my case. My VM where openstack is deployed has `25 GB Ram and 16 processor cores` while the host machine has `32 GB RAM and 32 logical processors (16 cores)`. How can I modify these variables or is there something else I am missing?

EDIT:
I was able to solve the problem by analyzing the output of `openstack hypervisor stats show`. The flavor I was using to extend the size was demanding more disk space (80G) then the one showed in hypervisor stats (47G). By extending the size of VM and then directory `/var/lib` (since i am using docker style deployment), the issue resolved.

Comment: up vote for this question also update my knowledge: `no valid host` relevant to the source limit setting including the flavor configure or source property like host aggregates, and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the `reserved_host_memory_mb` in **nova.conf**?

What's the version about your deployed `openstack`?

The [default `ram_allocation_ratio` is **1.5**](https://specs.openstack.org/openstack/nova-specs/specs/stein/implemented/initial-allocation-ratios.html#the-saga-of-the-allocation-ratio-values-on-the-compute-host), and you could set it to **2** or more, then check whether the error `No valid host was found.` fixed or not. This is the [Sample Configuration File](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/configuration/sample-config.html).

Get your hypervisor stats details by `openstack hypervisor stats show`. Make sure that system resource sufficiently, maybe there is some **limit** in your environment such as **ports**, **disk** or others.

Update for others reference:

The root cause is that the **flavor** with which instance was created has disk capacity **80G**, but only get `free_disk_gb` is **47** by `hypervisor stats`. And OP fixed it by extend the host(hypervisor)'s disk capacity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My openstack version is 5.2.1 and I have added these lines in nova.conf [default] portion but still the error remains same; `cpu_allocation_ratio = 2.0
ram_allocation_ratio = 2.0
reserved_host_memory_mb = 4096
reserved_host_cpus = 2`

Comment: What's the result of `openstack hypervisor stats show`. And the `cpu_allocation_ratio` usually set up to **4.0** in our environment.

Comment: +----------------------+-------+
| Field                | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| count                | 1     |
| current_workload     | 0     |
| disk_available_least | 19    |
| free_disk_gb         | 47    |
| free_ram_mb          | 9925  |
| local_gb             | 97    |
| local_gb_used        | 50    |
| memory_mb            | 24261 |
| memory_mb_used       | 14336 |
| running_vms          | 2     |
| vcpus                | 16    |
| vcpus_used           | 7     |
+----------------------+-------+

Comment: cpu_allocation_ratio=4.0 doesnot work either

Comment: What's the disk capacity of your instance? smaller than **47G** ? And your `free_ram_mb` could sufficient? Or you should try to create a small memory instance, check whether it works?

Comment: Thanks for cooperation. flavor with which instance is created has disk capacity 80G. As I mentioned going from 4GB Ram to 8GB was very smooth but upgrading to 16GB or 6 vcpus getting me this error. how to check `free_ram_mb`?

Comment: It had show at ` | free_ram_mb | 9925 |` through the `openstack hypervisor stats show` command. The key point is the `free_disk_gb` less than your flavor `Disk` setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244629/discussion-between-aneela-and-victor-lee).

Comment: I am facing same problem. i have 1 controller node and 1 compute node on baremetal. Im not sure how to increase the resources in openstack so it can use the host resources.