# Failed to create openStack ububtu 20 instance

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have Install open stack victoria on Ubuntu 20 and every think it ok , but  when t try to create instance from the Dashboard i got this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjyFs.png)

- Create of  the network from the dashbord success .
- I have the cirros image too.
- no error in th test of the service nova or neutron
  maybe , what is the problem ?

Comment: could you upload the more error log? also you could see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72171183/openstack-nova-resize-fail-nova-exception-novalidhost-no-valid-host-was-found/72171605#72171605

Comment: Your first step in diagnosing this error should be to inspect the logs for the Nova services on your controllers. These will typically be in `/var/log/nova`, although the location can differ depending on how things have been installed.